# Trashed list or Custom list for trashed items

Tags: react-admin

Is there a way to create a trash list?
Since I need to use soft deletes on my models I really need to create that list for the user restore tem items if he needs it.

I search in the docs but didn't found anything about it

Answer (score 0):

You might try creating a View in your database that represents the soft deleted (trashed) rows. Then register a resource in your app for that view. You could actually UNION a number of tables together that had soft deleted rows in them as long as you could get some common columns from each table in your view.

After you had this view and tested it out, you could hook a  to this view resource and let users view these deleted items.  You could then connect an action to the List such that they could un-soft delete a given row.